# How do I interpret rpart splits on factor variables when building classification trees in R?

Tags: r, rpart, cart-analysis

If the factor variable is Climate, with 4 possible values: Tropical, Arid, Temperate, Snow, and a node in my `rpart` tree is labeled as "Climate:ab", what is the split?

Comment: This belongs at stats.stackexchange.com and should be closed.

Comment: @Joris I disagree. Question is about interpretation of a program answer and has nothing to do with statistical background of partitioning trees and statistic itself.

Comment: @ Marek How else would you call the interpretation of a statistical analysis?

Comment: @user281537 You could at least give us the code and the output you're referring too. If Climate the y variable or one of your x variables? if it is "the" factor variable, I'd expect it to be the response variable. If it is, then it shouldn't be in a label at a node, but only at the leafs. The construct points in the direction of some interaction term.

Comment: @Marek : are you bouncing old questions by coincidence?

Comment: @Joris If I run into question with missing R tag or messed code formatting I usually don't look at the date. It's a little clean-up ;). And about question: I think that OP don't know what default label of rpart means.

Answer (score 11):

I assume you use standard way to plot tree which is

```
plot(f)
text(f)
```

As you can read in help to `text.rpart`, argument `pretty` on default factor variables are presented as letters, so `a` means `levels(Climate)[1]` and it means that on left node are observation with `Climate==levels(Climate)[1]` and on right the others.

You could print levels directly using

```
plot(f)
text(f, pretty=1)
```

[image: Created by rpart]

but I recommend using `draw.tree` from [maptree package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptree/index.html):

```
require(maptree)
draw.tree(f)
```

[image: Created by maptree]

I used fake data to do plots:

```
X <- data.frame(
    y=rep(1:4,25),
    Climate=rep(c("Tropical", "Arid", "Temperate", "Snow"),25)
)
f <- rpart(y~Climate, X)
```